# Text to speech converter

Tags: ios

I am looking for an iOS app that will convert a text to an audio file that I can then listen to in that app or export it to another audio-player app. So the app should not just read out the text, but give the option to convert to audio file (like mp3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several apps to do this. One is called [iSpeech](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ispeech-text-to-speech-pro/id540381415) which is highly rated. It may work only on text files but i'm not sure of that. Another popular app is [ClaroPDF](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/claropdf/id666770153) which is specifically for PDF files. It will read the files and save the reading as a sound file.

A good article rating the top [text to speech apps](https://www.easytechtrick.org/best-text-to-speech-apps/#FullReader) is found here